# SQL Server Managed Backup for Windows Azure (SSMBackup2WA) stuck waiting for progress update

Tags: sql-server, logging, backup

I have a database running on an azure vm with sql server. The db is in full recovery mode. The backup is configured through the web interface. Database and log backups have been working flawlessly for years. But recently the log backup was interrupted halfway through and the log backup process somehow got stuck. The following event has been logged every 5 minutes since then (reading log with managed_`backup.sp_get_backup_diagnostics`):

```
[SSMBackup2WAAdminXevent] Database Name = DB, Database ID = 777, Stage =
VerifyJobOutcome, Error Code = 0, Error Message = Warning, Additional Info = A 
progress update hasn't been received from SQL Server in more than 30 minutes 
for log backup. SSMBackup2WA will continue to wait.
```

`SSMBackup2WA` seem to be stuck waiting for a progress update never being received. This has resulted in no log backups being taken. The database backup have continued running without problem.

I have trouble finding the job/task used by `SSMBackup2WA`. I understand its not in the usual batch of SQL Server Agent jobs but somehow hidden.
My idea is to somehow cancel the existing job that is stuck in waiting loop but I have not figured out how.
I have tried to "reset" the backup process by turning off the backup and then turning it on again but that did not help.
I have no possibility to restart the sql server (and I don't know if that would help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since no one seemed to have an answer to this one I resorted to restarting the SQL-server. And after the restart the transaction log backup started working again!

What is interesting is the following log that appeared in the application event log during the restart. It does seem like there was a thread hanging indefinitely, waiting for an status update that never arrived. The restart seems to have taken care of it by killing this status thread and not restarting it again in the erroneous state it had ended up in.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft SQL Server Automated Backup
Date:          1/15/2022 11:16:20 AM
Event ID:      57007
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      wn-sqlserver1
Description:
[Warning] AutomatedBackupStatusMonitorError: 
  System.Exception: 
    Error in auto-backup status monitor thread ---> 

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IaaSAgentSqlQuery.Contract.IaaSAgentSqlQueryException: 
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not 
found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name 
is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote 
connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could 
not open a connection to SQL Server) --->
```